# CORS issue fails the communicatin within Magento 2 (Graphql) instance and React app: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:

Tags: magento2, graphql, cors, react-js

Getting following error trying to fetch data from react app.

1. Magento 2.4.2
2. Reac JS v17
3. Apollo/Client 3

   ```
    import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";


    export const client = new ApolloClient({ 
          uri: "https://someurl/graphql",
          cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    });
   ```

I also tried to add "no-cors" as suggested but still its not working

```
fetchOptions: {
    mode: 'no-cors',
  },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First I follow the error and according to this Request should be accepted by backend server , Magento website in my case.
We need to provide Cross site origin to use our resourse(graphql).
We can use available modules like [graycore/magento2-cors](https://github.com/graycoreio/magento2-cors) or just modify .htaccess ( Apache )

Add Headers to allow **content-type**

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:3000"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, OPTIONS"
```

- POST, OPTION, GET, PUT: You can provide methods as per you requirment

This above solution resoved the CORS error to access graphql from magetno website, But still there is an access control check failed, ***It does not have HTTP ok status***. and I recived below error:

[image]

For this I modified Rewrite Condition in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blank.html [QSA,L]
```

Hope this post is helpful.